# Grails: showing error message in web flow

Tags: grails, spring-webflow

I want to show my domains error message in .gsp but somehow I'm not able to..
In my Controller,

```
class SomethingController {
    def index(){
        redirect(action: "create")
    }

    def createFlow = {
        stepOne {
            on("submit"){
                domain = new Domain(firstColumn: params.firstColumn)

                if(!domain.validate()){
                    return error()
                } else {
                    return success()
                }
            }.to "stepTwo"  
        }
        stepTwo {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

And in my .gsp, I have:

```
<g:renderErrors bean="${domain}" />
```

I'm definitely sure that if i "println domain.errors" i get validation error message. However, when failed in stepOne, I don't see any error message as well as ${domain.errors} outputs 0 errors.

Please help... this might be a stupid mistake I'm doing...

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to pass the domain object or any other value through the flow something like this (not tested):

```
class SomethingController {
def index(){
    redirect(action: "create")
}

def createFlow = {
    stepOne {
        on("submit"){
            domain = new Domain(firstColumn: params.firstColumn)

            if(!domain.validate()){


                flow.domain= domain
                // or 
                flow.errorMessages="this is an error"


                return error()
            } else {
                return success()
            }
        }.to "stepTwo"  
    }
    stepTwo {
        ...
    }
}
```

}

and display it on your view like this:

```
 <div>${errorMessages}</div>
 <g:renderErrors bean="${domain}" />
```

Comment: Is this the right way of doing it? you renderErrors will anyway output nothing. I just don't want to use $errorMessages like what you did here but do it in Grails way (using renderErrors).

Comment: There are always different ways doing one thing and this approach is not wrong if it works for you. However, if you try the errorMessages way you will have to handle the rendering yourself. Also put your renderErrors in a has errorrs tag. <g:hasErrors bean="${domain}">
   <div class="errors">
      <g:renderErrors bean="${domain}" as="list" />
   </div>
</g:hasErrors>